# Keep getting errors using Eloquent Relationships Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I keep getting trying to get property of non-object anything am using laravel Eloquent Relationships. i Know that the eloquent relationship code is correct but i keep getting error.

This is my Video Controller

```
   class Video extends Model
  {
protected $fillable = [
    'vid',
    'v_img',
    'v_bg_img',
    'v_title',
    'v_description',
    'category_id',
    'previous_view',
    'previous_like',
    'today_view',
    'today_like',
    'daily_view',
    'daily_like',
    'weekly_view',
    'weekly_like',
    'promoted',
    'linked',
    'vid_entry_date'
];


public function videoRank()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\VideoRank', 'category_id');
}
   }
```

This is my Video Rank Controller

```
  class VideoRank extends Model
      {

protected $fillable = [
    'rankName',
    'minRank',
    'maxRank'
];

public function video(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Video','category_id');
}
```

}

This is my blade view

```
               @foreach($videos as $video)
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">

                        <td>{{$video->videoRank->rankName}}</td>


                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

I keep getting error 'Trying to get property of non-object '

Comment: Could you paste your controller as well? It seems that one of the videos doesn't have a videoRank assigned

Comment: `public function artistVideo(){
        $artists = Artist::all();
        $videoRanks = VideoRank::all();
        $videos = Video::all();

        return view('superAdmin.artists.video')
            ->with(compact('artists','videoRanks','videos'));
    }`